vtkPolyDataEdgeConnectivityFilter: update borders after Large/SmallRegionGrowing
I use vtkPolyDataEdgeConnectivityFilter to segment a mesh based on selected edges. After obtaining the segmentation, I run vtkSmallRegionGrow. At this point, I would like to apply vtkLargeRegionGrow on the new regions identified by SmallRegionGrow. To do this, I need the new edges that define the boundaries of the regions found by SmallRegionGrow. Currently, I extract these edges manually, but this significantly increases execution time. Is there a way to have the filter directly return these edges in VTK?
I'm working in python 3.12 using pyvista 0.44.1 and vtk 9.3.1.
feature_edges = PolyData(mesh.points, lines=edges.reshape(-1))
f = vtkPolyDataEdgeConnectivityFilter()
f.SetExtractionModeToAllRegions()
f.SetColorRegions(True)
f.SetInputData(mesh)
f.BarrierEdgesOn()
f.SetBarrierEdges(True)
f.SetSourceData(feature_edges)
f.Update()
f.SetLargeRegionThreshold(sml_thr)
f.GrowSmallRegionsOn()
f.Update()
f.SetSourceData(newborders(mesh)
f.SetLargeRegionThreshold(lrg_thr)
f.GrowLargeRegionsOn()
f.Update()


def newborders(mesh):
     edges = []
     for i in range(mesh.n_cells):
         for j in range(len(mesh.cell_neighbors(i,'edges'))):
              if mesh['RegionId'][i] != mesh['RegionId'][mesh.cell_neighbors(i,'edges')[j]]:
                  edge = np.intersect1d(mesh.get_cell(i).point_ids,mesh.get_cell(mesh.cell_neighbors(i,'edges')[j]).point_ids)
                  edges.append([2 , edge[0], edge[1]])
     return np.array(edges)


I'm not familiar with the filter and it's not clear to me what's going on here, but from a pure programming point of view there's things I'd try to optimize your manual loop. You're mesh.cell_neighbors(i, 'edges')[j] gets called several times, and I bet that's not trivial to compute. I'd define this quantity once for an (i, j) pair. Actualy, you probably only need for neighb in mesh.cell_neighbors(i, 'edge') instead of for j in .... And I'd try pre-computing quantities where possible. E.g. if the meshes are not too large, set(mesh.get_cell(i).point_ids for each i to intersect.

Thank you, this helps a bit. I quickly wrote the manual part yesterday, but the computation times are still far too high (I’m working with meshes with several million faces). It seems strange that VTK doesn’t have a method to extract the edges identified by its own filter, probably because it operates on cells for the SmallRegionGrow and LargeRegionGrow algorithms. However, even another function to extract the boundary edges between cells with different labels would be useful.
